# How to keep a flexbox same height as viewport (no scrolling)?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs in a flexbox (div id="content_row") with flex-direction = row to represent 3 lists.
None of the lists should grow, if ones content bigger than the screen can display, the list itself should add a scroll bar and not the whole webpage.

Cause of this I put that flexbox in another flexbox with flex-direction = column and gave it a flex of 1. Is there an attribute I can add to prevent this flexbox from growing?

I know I could simply add the overflow property to the lists but I had trouble with that in the past. There is always one browser that displays it the wrong way.

```
#content_row{ display: flex; flex-direction: row;}
.row-item{ flex: 0.33; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;}
#content_column{ display: flex; flex-direction: column;}
#content_row_wrapper{ flex: 1;}

<div id="content_column">
 <div id="content_row_wrapper">
  <div id="content_row">
   <div class=".row-item"></div>
   <div class=".row-item"></div>
   <div class=".row-item"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Cheers

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: shared above :-)

Answer (score 0):

add and remove text to see the changes, if you don't want the scrolbar on your webpage, then you need to make overflow hidden of body and apply the same on your content div. now the scrollbar is on your content row, not on body, remove data and it will be gone.

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
}
#content_row{ display: flex; flex-direction: row; overflow-y: auto;     max-height: 300px;}
.row-item{ flex: 0.33; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;}

#content_column{ display: flex; flex-direction: column;}
#content_row_wrapper{ flex: 1;}
```

```html
<div id="content_column">
 <div id="content_row_wrapper">
  <div id="content_row">
   <div class="row-item">
    More content foemo purposeMore content for demo purpose More content for demo purposeMore content for demo purpose More content for demo pur for demo purposeMore content for demo purpose More content for demo purposeMore content foreMore content for demo purpose More content for demo purposeMore content for demo purpose More content for demo purposeMore content r demo purposeMore content for demo purpose More content for demo pur for demo purposeMore content for demo purpose More content for demo purposeMore content foreMore content for demo purpose More content for demo purposeMore content for demo purpose More content for demo purposeMore content for demo purposez atul
</div>
<div class="row-item">2nd Div</div>
<div class="row-item"> 3rd Div</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: just one thing, as you mentioned in your question, if you want your item's minimum height equal to viewport height, then do it with css .row-item {min-height: 100vh;}